# Filtering a vector on condition

Tags: r, vector, filter

I am trying to filter a vector of integers.
My condition is that the distance between 2 consecutive elements should be at least 100 ; if not, remove the element and look at the next candidate.
Here is an example :

```
set.seed(42)
input <- sort(sample(1:1000, 20))
head(input, 20)


[1] 24  49  74 128 146 153 165 228 303 321 356 410 532 561 601 622 634 839 882 997
```

If I start from the first element `24`, I would like to keep the first element that has a distance at least 100 from it.
In this case, it would be `128`.

Then, from `128`, repeat the same process.
The result should be :

```
24 128 228 356 532 634 839 997
```

I managed to create a quick and dirty loop that gives the correct result, but I can guess that it would not be very efficient for very large vectors...

```
result <- integer(length(input))
result[1] <- input[1]
for(i in seq_along(input)[-1]) {
  if(is.na(input[2])) break

  if(input[2] - input[1] < 100) {
    input <- input[-2]
  } else {
    result[i] <- input[2]
    input <- input[-1]
  }
}

result <- result[result != 0]
```

What would be an efficient way to get the expected result ? Can it be done using vectorization ?

Comment: Related: [Subset observations that differ by at least 30 minutes time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918158/subset-observations-that-differ-by-at-least-30-minutes-time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
unique(Reduce(function(x,y)ifelse(y-x>=100,y,x),input,accumulate = T))
[1]  24 128 228 356 532 634 839 997
```

Comment: Friends don't let friends use `ifelse()` for scalar comparisons, or `T` for `TRUE`: `unique(Reduce(function(x, y) if (y - x >= 100) y else x, input, accumulate = TRUE))`

Comment: @MartinMorgan I agree. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not thoroughly tested, but I believe this gets you there. I am using `purrr::accumulate`. This is a pretty neat problem :-) hoping to see some other solutions/approaches, so maybe leave this open (unanswered) for a bit...

```
library(purrr)

input <- c(24, 49, 74, 128, 146, 153, 165, 228, 303, 321, 356, 410, 532, 561, 601, 622, 634, 839, 882, 997)
idx <- which(accumulate(diff(input), ~ ifelse(.x >= 100, .y, .x + .y)) >= 100)
input[c(1, idx + 1)]
#> [1]  24 128 228 356 532 634 839 997
```

And to make this read a little more `purrr`, I suppose we could do:

```
accumulate(diff(input), ~ if_else(.x >= 100, .y, .x + .y)) %>%
  map_lgl(~ . >= 100) %>%
  which %>%
  { input[c(1, . + 1)] }
```